# File upload in codeigniter in IE: The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter, internet-explorer, file-upload

I am using codeigniter and jQuery form plugin.

I am trying to upload a file but its not working with IE.

Please check my controller:

```
    if($fileCount >0)

    {

    //there are some files



    //configure upload


    $config['upload_path'] = 'crm_data/crm_customer_data';

    $config['allowed_types'] = 'zip|rar|doc|pdf|gif|jpg|jpeg|docx';

    $config["max_size"] = 2048;

    $config['encrypt_name'] = true;


    //loading upload

    $this->load->library("upload");

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

if($this->upload->do_upload("attach"))

        {

        $l = $this->upload->data();

        $logs["attachment"] =  $l["file_name"];


        }

    else

    {

    //some errors on upload                             exit(json_encode(array("status"=>FALSE,"reason"=>$this->upload->display_errors())));

    }
```

Here is the html

```
<input type="file" id="attach" name="attach" />
```

IT WORKS WELL IN OTHER BROWSERS except IE.

see the response.

```
var_dump($_FILES)


array
  'attach' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'invoice_record_and_list.zip' (length=31)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpF467.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 1467474
```

IN IE i am getting the following errors .

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

EDIT:

I noted something var_dump on IE gives me a `""` for `type`but in FF i got `'type' => string 'application/x-zip-compressed' (length=28)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help.

IE not sending your mime type for 'zip' (eg: `'type' => string`).
so just append an empty value with the file types like this in your config/memi.ph.

`'zip'  =>  array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed',"")`